# Prove $\{f_{k}\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

> Let $\{ f_{k} \}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[a, b]$.
>   Show that if $\{ f_{k} \}$ converges uniformly on $(a, b)$, then it
>   converges uniformly on $[a, b]$.

I attempted to use $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ definitions of uniform Cauchy and continuity, but I am really not sure about how to proceed. Below is what I have so far:

Because $\{ f_{k} \}$ converges uniformly on $(a, b)$, $\{ f_{k} \}$ is uniformly Cauchy on $(a, b)$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a large $K$ s.t.
$$|f_{j} (x) - f_{k} (x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3} \ \textrm{whenever} \ j, k > K \ \textrm{and} \ x \in (a, b)$$

Because $f_{j} (x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, there exists $\delta' > 0$ such that $|f_{j} (x) - f_{j} (a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ whenever $|x - a| < \delta'$. Similarly, since $f_{k} (x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, there exists $\delta'' > 0$ such that $|f_{k} (x) - f_{k}(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ whenever $|x - a| < \delta''$.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have $|f_{j} (x) - f_{k} (x)| <  \frac{\epsilon}{3} \ \textrm{whenever} \ j, k > K \ \textrm{and} \ x \in (a, b)$ you can take limits as $x \to a$ and $x \to b$ to get  $|f_{j} (x) - f_{k} (x)| \leq  \frac{\epsilon}{3} \ \textrm{whenever} \ j, k > K \ \textrm{and} \ x \in [a, b]$ so we see that the sequence is Cauchy in the closed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Could you expand on how to take limits as $x \to a$ and $x \to b$?

Comment: You just fix $j,k >K$ and take limits. Since $f_j(x) \to f_j(a)$ and $f_k(x) \to f_k(a)$ as $x \to a$ we get the inequality when $x=a$. Similarly for $x=b$.@ferrous

Comment: Do you mean something like $|(f_{j}(x) - f_{k}(x)) - (f_{j}(a) - f_{k}(a))| \leq |f_{j}(x) - f_{j}(a)| + |f_{k}(x) - f_{k}(a)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$? Or do you mind typing it up? Sorry I am having a hard time with these $\delta$ $\epsilon$ arguments. @Kavi Rama Murthy